# CodeDom Compiler подключение ссылки

Tags: c#, ссылки, компилятор

Как подключить ссылку к создаваемому приложению? К примеру System.Management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Management.dll");
```